# Post with ajax ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(Contact contact)
    {
        using (LawContext DB = new LawContext())
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                DB.Contact.Add(contact);
                DB.SaveChanges();
                return Json("OK");
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
```

View

```
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Contact", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                        @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                                @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "alert-danger" })
                        }
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Lastname, new { @class = "form-control margin-bottom10", @placeholder = "Name" })

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mail, new { @class = "form-control margin-bottom10", @placeholder = "Mail" })

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone, new { @class = "form-control margin-bottom10", @placeholder = "Phone" })

                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control margin-bottom10", @placeholder = "Message", @rows = "3" })

                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-darkgray" id="btn_contact" />
                }
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_contact").click(function () {

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "Contact/Index", 
                data: { 
                    Lastname: $("#Lastname").val(),
                    Mail: $("#Mail").val(),
                    Phone: $("#Phone").val(),
                    Message: $("#Message").val()
                },
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charsetset=utf8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert('failure');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
    });
});
```

I do not understand why this is happening
Do not normally have to be alerted?
How can I do this properly? I would like your help.
I have studied many examples.
I guess I lost hope I could do without asking.

I would like to work well.

Comment: The way you are doing now  is you are using the form submit button to call `index` action on `ContactController` which returns view that's why empty page with just ok. If you want to use ajax to call the same action try use a normal button give it id `btn_contact`. The rest of the code looks fine.  I haven't tested it, but it should work(pop an alert).

Comment: You making both a an ajax call and a normal submit. You need to cancel the default submit - `$("#btn_contact").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault; $.ajax(....` or add `return false;` as the last line of code in your method. As a side note there is no need to wrap `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in the `if` block

Comment: In addition, `return View();` makes no sense because you never do anything with the view you return

Comment: @StephenMuecke When I did not check, the style I gave seemed empty

Comment: Yes, that's what is supposed to happen (it will be used for client side validation). But since you have no validation at all (either client or server side) then you may as well delete `@Html.ValidationSummary()` as well since its pointless

Comment: And as a side note, just use `data: $('form').serialize(),` and remove `contentType: "application/json; charsetset=utf8",` (the model in your POST method would not even be binding with your current code when you make the ajax POST). You can also remove  `async: true,` (that's the default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your submit button to:
`<input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-darkgray" id="btn_contact" />`

Or you can leave it as is and in your Ajax call, do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_contact").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "Contact/Index", 
                data: { 
                    Lastname: $("#Lastname").val(),
                    Mail: $("#Mail").val(),
                    Phone: $("#Phone").val(),
                    Message: $("#Message").val()
                },
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charsetset=utf8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert('failure');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
    });
});
```

This is so as to prevent the default behaviour of the submit type button which sends the form to the action url (`<form action="contact/index" method="POST" ...`) which in your case you don't have.